# Oselection reading state

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-mobile

this is my model

```
OColumn state_order = new OColumn("state_order", OSelection.class)
.addSelection("draft","New")
.addSelection("paid","Paid")
.addSelection("cancel","Cancelled")
.addSelection("done","Posted")
.addSelection("invoiced","Invoiced")
```

In my Fragment I need to read state_order value
This is my code

```
 public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
  OControls.setText(view, R.id.state, row.getString("state_order"));
   }
```

But he show me False value
what can I DO !

Comment: Please add the model name in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The field `state_order` must be present in the server with the same name.
Even if it works you will get `draft` instead of `Draft Quotation`, and to get the value (not the key) you will need to add a local computed column:

```
@Odoo.Functional(method = "stateTitle", store=true, depends = {"state"})
OColumn state_title = new OColumn("State title", OVarchar.class)
       .setLocalColumn();

public String stateTitle (OValues values){
    HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap();
            hm.put ("draft", "Draft Quotation");
            hm.put ("sent", "Quotation Sent");
            hm.put ("cancel", "Cancelled");
            hm.put ("waiting_date", "Waiting Schedule");
            hm.put ("progress", "Sales Order");
            hm.put ("manual", "Sale to Invoice");
            hm.put ("shipping_except", "Shipping Exception");
            hm.put ("invoice_except", "Invoice Exception");
            hm.put ("done", "Done");

    return  hm.get(values.getString("state"));
}
```